# Find email domain in address with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, email, search, dns

I know I'm an idiot, but I can't pull the domain out of this email address:

```
'blahblah@gmail.com'
```

My desired output:

```
'@gmail.com'
```

My current output:

```
.
```

(it's just a period character)

Here's my code:

```
import re
test_string = 'blahblah@gmail.com'
domain = re.search('@*?\.', test_string)
print domain.group()
```

Here's what I think my regular expression says ('@*?.', test_string):

```
 ' # begin to define the pattern I'm looking for (also tell python this is a string)

  @ # find all patterns beginning with the at symbol ("@")

  * # find all characters after ampersand

  ? # find the last character before the period

  \ # breakout (don't use the next character as a wild card, us it is a string character)

  . # find the "." character

  ' # end definition of the pattern I'm looking for (also tell python this is a string)

  , test string # run the preceding search on the variable "test_string," i.e., 'blahblah@gmail.com'
```

I'm basing this off the definitions here:

http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/4.4/regex-intro.html

Also, I searched but other answers were a bit too difficult for me to get my head around.

Help is much appreciated, as usual.  Thanks.

My stuff if it matters:

> Windows 7 Pro (64 bit)
>
> Python 2.6 (64 bit)

---

PS. StackOverflow quesiton: My posts don't include new lines unless I hit "return" twice in between them. For example (these are all on a different line when I'm posting):

@ - find all patterns beginning with the at symbol ("@")
* - find all characters after ampersand
? - find the last character before the period
\ - breakout (don't use the next character as a wild card, us it is a string character)
. - find the "." character
, test string - run the preceding search on the variable "test_string," i.e., 'blahblah@gmail.com'

That's why I got a blank line b/w every line above.  What am I doing wrong? Thx.

Comment: To answer your PS (which should be on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)): Stack Overflow uses *Markdown*. From the formatting instructions: "for linebreak add 2 spaces at end"

Comment: It will accept html such as <br />

Comment: A simple solution is "@.*", though it might be too greedy for your tastes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's something I think might help

```
import re
s = 'My name is Conrad, and blahblah@gmail.com is my email.'
domain = re.search("@[\w.]+", s)
print domain.group()
```

outputs

```
@gmail.com
```

How the regex works:

`@` - scan till you see this character

`[\w.]` a set of characters to potentially match, so `\w` is all alphanumeric characters, and the trailing period `.` adds to that set of characters.

`+` one or more of the previous set.

Because this regex is matching the period character and every alphanumeric after an `@`, it'll match email domains even in the middle of sentences.

Answer (score 18):

Ok, so why not use split? (or partition )

```
"@"+'blahblah@gmail.com'.split("@")[-1]
```

Or you can use other string methods like find

```
>>> s="bal@gmail.com"
>>> s[ s.find("@") : ]
'@gmail.com'
>>>
```

and if you are going to extract out email addresses from some other text

```
f=open("file")
for line in f:
    words= line.split()
    if "@" in words:
       print "@"+words.split("@")[-1]
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Why regex and not regular string methods? I have 40 megs of string with email addresses intermingled with junk text that I am trying to extract.  I'm a hobbyist programmer and I try to keep things simple and to play with the regex so I could understand it, so I didn't go into it here.  Sorry if that was confusing.

Answer (score 8):

Using regular expressions:

```
>>> re.search('@.*', test_string).group()
'@gmail.com'
```

A different way:

```
>>> '@' + test_string.split('@')[1]
'@gmail.com'
```

Comment: Ahh. I see I needed the other '.'  Thanks!!  (not sure why though).

Comment: @AquaT33nFan: `"@*"` means 0 or more occurrences of `"@"`. `"@.*"` means one occurrence of `"@"` followed by 0 or more occurrences of any character (except a newline). In other words, `*` here is a [Kleene star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star), not a [wildcard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk#Computer_interfaces).

Answer (score 3):

You can try using urllib

```
from urllib import parse
email = 'myemail@mydomain.com'
domain = parse.splituser(email)[1]
```

Output will be

```
'mydomain.com'
```

Comment: The `splituser` function is deprecated. https://bugs.python.org/issue35891

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to point out that chrisaycock's method would match invalid email addresses of the form

```
herp@
```

to correctly ensure you're just matching a possibly valid email with domain you need to alter it slightly

Using regular expressions:

```
>>> re.search('@.+', test_string).group()
'@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the below regular expression you can extract any domain like .com or .in.

```
import re
s = 'my first email is user1@gmail.com second email is enter code hereuser2@yahoo.in and third email is user3@outlook.com'
print(re.findall('@+\S+[.in|.com|]',s))
```

output

```
['@gmail.com', '@yahoo.in']
```

Comment: This limits the possible domains due to it only accounting for 2 top level domains.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method using the index function:

```
email_addr = 'blahblah@gmail.com'

# Find the location of @ sign
index = email_addr.index("@")

# extract the domain portion starting from the index
email_domain = email_addr[index:]

print(email_domain)
#------------------
# Output:
@gmail.com
```