# Splitting, Sorting and Counting of email-addresses in an txt.file at the @ sign with python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, sqlite

I need to split email-addresses aaaa.nnnn.@**universityxyz.edu**. at the @, that I can **count the different universities** and **sort them from max to min**.

With this code:

```
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith('From: ') : continue
    pieces = line.split()
    org = pieces[1]
    #print line.split()
    cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE org = ? ', (org, ))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Counts (org, count) 
                VALUES ( ?, 2 )''', ( org, ) )
```

How can I sort (max-min) and sum the organizations?

[Python Regular Expressions, find Email Domain in Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629907/python-regular-expressions-find-email-domain-in-address)

Comment: What does your code have to do with  the question? Whats the problem? Whats not working? Where is the minimal example? How does your text file look like?

Comment: The code is the part of my code where my loop starts and iterates over the email-adresses in my file. The email is an string and I can not split it, at least I don't know HOW .. As I said, I need the email not as one string but splitted at the @ sign to get only the organizations. After that I need to count the emails from one organisation and sort the organisations from max email count to min email count ... The Example is what I posted. The text-file is an txt. file ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file called `file.txt`:

```
From: foo@bar.com
From: foo2@bar.com
From: foo3@car.com
From: foo5@car.com
From: foo@bar.com
random text
From: foo2@bar.com
From: foo4@sar.com
```

Python code:

```
from collections import Counter
domains = Counter()

fh = open('file.txt')

for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith('From: ') : continue
    pieces = line.split()
    email = pieces[1]
    if '@' in email:
        domain = email.split('@')[1]
        domains[domain] += 1

print domains.most_common()
```

You will get:

```
[('bar.com', 4), ('car.com', 2), ('sar.com', 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you @mingham, for your answer. I still dont know what is wrong Here is the code now:                                                                                 `print "Counts:"
for row in cur.execute(sqlstr) :
    if '@' in row:
        domain = org.split('@')[1]
        domains [domain] += 1
        print str(row[0]), row[1]
print domains.most_common()`
But I still get in the result **stonlia.marquxxx@mct.axx.ta** **count user** instead of ***@mct.axx.ta** **count of organisation** ...

Comment: It works fine by itself but I need to combine it with a sqlite3-file and that doesn't work ...

Comment: Thank You I got the solution and your code was a great help !!