# Is there a builtin library in Python that can parse out the domain part (if any) of an email address?

Tags: python, email-address

I know that I can use `email.utils.parseaddr` to parse out an email address properly, even a tricksy one:

```
>>> parseaddr('Bad Horse <bad.horse@example(no one expects the @-ish inquisition!).com')
('Bad Horse (no one expects the @-ish inquisition!)', 'bad.horse@example.com')
```

(So good, Python! So good!)

However, that's just a string:

```
>>> type(parseaddr('Bad Horse <bad.horse@example(no one expects the @-ish inquisition!).com')[-1])
<class 'str'>
```

In the typical case I can just do `.rsplit('@', maxsplit=1)[-1]` to get the domain. But what if I'm just sending local mail without a domain?

```
>>> parseaddr('Wayne <wayne>')[-1].rsplit('@', maxsplit=1)[-1]
'wayne'
```

That's not quite what I want - I'd prefer maybe `None` or `'localhost'`.

Does anything like that come in Python's included batteries?

Comment: The return type of `parseaddr()` is a tuple, not a string. I'm puzzled how you got the output you show.

Comment: Here is [virtually the same code on ideone](https://ideone.com/exaAW9), and it prints `<class 'tuple'>`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach `parseaddr(...)[-1]` helps an awful lot getting the last element in a tuple ;)

Comment: regex would work great for this

Comment: @KurtisStreutker after applying parseaddr, possibly. RFC valid email addresses apparently can have arbitrarily nested comments

Comment: @KurtisStreutker see http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html for more fun and excitement

Comment: @WayneWerner My point is that the second code example in your question does not have the output you claim it has, which made it harder for me to understand the question.

Comment: @SvenMarnach did you copy and paste or type the code? Your ideone code is missing the [-1] from my second code sample

Comment: @WayneWerner I am very confused. The code I see in your second code block is this: `type(parseaddr('Bad Horse <bad.horse@example(no one expects the @-ish inquisition!).com'))` (copy-pasted). I can't see any `[-1]`, even when looking at the source code.

Comment: Ooo, the *second* part. Yeah, apparently *I* just typed that one in instead of copy/paste. My bad >.> - fixed!

Comment: You could define your own function that checks for a domain with regex and otherwise defaults to localhost.

Comment: @WayneWerner I'm glad we managed to sort this out. It wasn't _actually_ that relevant, but I started to question my own sanity. :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find anything yet, so my current approach is to make a slight adjustment:

```
try:
    domain = parseaddr('Wayne <wayne>')[-1].rsplit('@', maxsplit=1)[1]
except IndexError:
    # There was no '@' in the email address
    domain = None  # or 'localhost'
```

In the absence of a better way, this works and gets me what I need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629907/python-regular-expressions-find-email-domain-in-address