# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) Wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following code:

```
file = input("Email LIST : ")
in_emails = open(file,'r',errors='ignore').read().splitlines()
    
    domain_set = set()
    
    out_emails = []
    
    for email in in_emails:
        _, tmp = email.split("@", maxsplit=1)
        domain, _ = tmp.split(":", maxsplit=1)
        if domain not in domain_set:
            out_emails.append(email)
            domain_set.add(domain)
    
    print(out_emails)
```

I am getting the error below:

```
_, tmp = email.split("@", maxsplit=1) ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Any solution for ignoring wrong Lines ?

Comment: Try `print(email)` before you do the `split`s.  I think you will likely find an empty line that doesn't contain an `@`.

Comment: We can't see the contents of the most crucial part; the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find email domain in address with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5629907/7758804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pave over anything that goes wrong and log it like this:

```py
for email in in_emails:

    try:
        _, tmp = email.split("@", maxsplit=1)
        domain, _ = tmp.split(":", maxsplit=1)
        if domain not in domain_set:
            out_emails.append(email)
            domain_set.add(domain)
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Failed to parse email '{email}'", err)
```

Comment: You could catch both potential split exceptions with `try/except` instead of check and `continue`.

Comment: Im getting : 
    if not email.contains("@"):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: Also i already check my list , they all have "@"

Comment: Changed to try/except as suggested by @theherk.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not passing any empty string to email.
If email doesn't contain `@` the split will always return a single value. And you can't unpack (or assign) a single value into two variables.

`_, tmp = "random@gmail.com".split("@", maxsplit=1)` It works.

`_, tmp = "randomemail".split("@", maxsplit=1)` It will throw error.

For more information about split method, see here: [python-split](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html)

Comment: i already check all lines using notepad++ , They all have "@".